# Printing GitRepo Name to vs code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Printing the name of gitrepo which the user is currently working on to screen or vscode

https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-repo-info
Tried using info and many other but complete path is printed out not the repo name

```
branch(`${folderPath}`)
        .then(name =>{
var info = getRepoInfo(`${folderPath}\.git`);
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(info.branch)
        }) //=> 'master' 
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

only repo name i wanted to be displayed

Comment: Problem is the notion of a repo name doesn't even exist. A git repo never has a "repo name", what you might want is the containing folder's name, or the last part of the full path. Simply do `folderPath.split('\').pop()` to get that name.

Comment: Do you mean the last part of the URL of a _remote_ (as there may be multiple)?